# Strange error line displayed for JSX file in Atom

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor

This error is displayed for first JSX tag in every JSX file. No any other text is displayed, no notification, no message. Cannot trace which plugin causes this - tried to disabled all with no success. Any idea? Atom 1.0.19 with atom-react 0.12.10 plugin

[image]